# Quebra de linha em JavaScript não está funcionando

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando inserir uma quebra de linha em um código simples:

```
 var meuNome = "Danilo Costa";
var idade = 18;
var ocupacao = "dev Front End";
var interesses = [
    ['Jogos',['world of warcraft']],
    ['musica',['SuperCombo']],
    ['livros',['O nome da rosa - Umberto Eco']]];

document.write('Olá, eu me chamo '+ meuNome +', tenho '+idade +' anos, e sou um ' + ocupacao + ' \nmeus interesses são:'+interesses[0]);
```

Quando eu vou executar esse código, a quebra de linha na parte "\nmeusinteresses" não funciona...
Por que isso ocorre?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já testaste com `<br>` em vez de `\n`?

Comment: `\n` quebra linha apenas no HTML (inspecione o elemento e verá o resultado). Como o Sergio disse, experimente a tag `<br>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sugestão do @Sergio é perfeita, estou escrevendo essa resposta apenas para esclarecer o comportamento do HTML em relação aos espaços...

O que acontece é que, no caso do seu exemplo, o HTML está ignorando as quebras e deixando como espaços. Isso acontece por conta da propriedade `white-space` do `css`.

Veja mais aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Como está usando um  `document.write`, deve estar escrevendo para o `body`, que por default tem essa propriedade como "normal", que faz com se comporte assim, conforme documetação do link acima:

> "Sequências de espaços em branco são recolhidas. Caracteres de nova
>   linha no código são tratados como outros espaços em branco. As linhas
>   quebram conforme a necessidade para preencher as linhas das caixas
>   (boxes)."

Ou seja, as quebras são tratadas como espaços. Agora, se utilizar um elemento que tenha outro comportamento de `white-space`, ou mudar a propriedade `white-space` no `body`, ele pode mudar como as quebras de linha aparecem, veja isso:

```js
document.write("<pre>");
document.write("Linha1\nLinha2\nLinha3");
document.write("</pre>");
```

Para o exemplo acima, usei o elemento `<pre>`, que por padrão tem a propriedade `white-space` como `pre`. O incoveniente é que o elemento tem outros estilos.

Veja agora se mudar o comportamento do `body` (apenas a título de estudo para ver como funciona), e de quebra, vou usar o método `writeln` que já adiciona uma quebra de linha sem precisar do `\n`:

```js
document.writeln("---- isso é um teste ----");
document.writeln("Linha1");
document.writeln("Linha2");
document.writeln("Linha3");
```

```css
body {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Então o comportamento pode ser controlado com `css`, evitando `<br>`, mas isso depende do contexto e de como está a página. De qualquer forma, ainda evite usar `document.write`, é preferível criar um elemento e adicionar o conteúdo diretamente a ele (div, por exemplo), isso ajuda a controlar melhor o HTML, e pode usar outras formatações.